# How to changue the background colour of a item of a listview programatically?

Tags: android, android-listview

i have a listview, and i need to changue the background colour of a item, for example the item 2.

I tryed with this code but it crash because the third line gives nullpointerexception, but the list haves 11 items!!! i dont understand where is the problem

```
CalendarList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.CalendarList);
CalendarList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, MyApplication.roundMatches(CalendarPicker.getValue())));
CalendarList.getChildAt(2).setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);
```

Comment: Please post your Activity code below the excerpt and I will take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally none of these solutions works, i did this by a different way, changing the colour of the text and not of the background

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the ListView is highly optimized to only create the views needed to be actually shown on the screen. So, getChildAt() will return null for rows that have not been created. Just check for a null return from getChildAt(). If row 2 (in this case) does not yet exist, it will later get created when the row is inflated (with getView(), bindView(), etc). You can just set the appropriate color at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setBackgroundResource(R.color.myRow_red)` instead of setBackgroundColor(). In your example background color is assigned with the ID instead of the actual color described in the resources. but first you should check `getChildAt()` return null for rows that have been created or not? before you are applying the `setBackgroundColor()`

Comment: how to create that backgroundcolour? how to make that xml with that resource? can you give me the xml code? and, where i have to put that xml?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="background">#3500ffff</color> 
 <color name="transparent_blue">#80004488........</color>
<color name="black">#ff000000</color>
<color name="darker_gray">#ffaaaaaa</color>
<color name="white">#ffffffff</color></resources>

Comment: and this XML file inside the res/values/color (here color.xml is the file name that has above elements mean color name and values)